# Koch Curve java

Tags: java, recursion, fractals

I have been given an assignment to draw a Koch Curve and Koch Snowflake recursively. I seem to be typing in the same code that everybody else is doing, but it simply wont work. The problem is, instead of replacing the lines with a smaller version of itself, like it is supposed to do, it is just continuing on one line, repeating itself and never getting smaller. Here is my code. Can somebody please help me?

```
public void draw(double level, double length)
{
    if (level < 1)
    {
        myPencil.forward(length);
    }

    else
    {
        draw(level - 1, (length) / 3);
        myPencil.turnLeft(60);
        draw(level - 1, (length) / 3);
        myPencil.turnRight(120);
        draw(level - 1, (length) / 3);
        myPencil.turnLeft(60);
        draw(level - 1, (length) / 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of copying the "code that everybody else is doing", you should try something yourself.

Comment: Also, what specifically about it isn't working?

Comment: Getting errors? Incorrect output? If it's drawing a pentagram instead of a snowflake, your system could be posessed. Are you using Windows?

Comment: @DennisMeng Well basically, instead of replacing the lines with a smaller version of itself, like it is supposed to do, it is just continuing on one line, repeating itself and never getting smaller.

Comment: @JakeChavis Then state that in the question up-front; don't make people guess what the issue is.

Comment: For one thing I'd guess that you want `length` instead of `myLength`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard when I do that, there is only a dot that appears on the sketchpad.

Comment: @DennisMeng ok so I just edited the question. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: What are you using for your starting values?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard well I have the user input the values, but I have been inputting level 5 and length of 150.

Comment: Well, it's not going to draw anything until `level == 0`, so with those values, `length` will be 150 divided by 3, 5 times, and since we're talking about integer division, the length that is actually drawn will be zero.

Comment: I think you need to re-examine your logic. Should it draw only when `level` is 0, or on every iteration? Do you have your pencil turns happening at the right places, in the right order?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard thank you for correcting the integer issue. I changed the value to double values. But when I did this, it looked as if there were really small Koch curves being made continuously, not going to stop. Any ideas? I do believe I have the order of everything correct.

Comment: @JakeChavis read more carefully. The solution has already been told to you. "it's not going to draw anything until level == 0"

Comment: @RobinGreen I understand that it doesn't draw until level== 0. It is a base case. What I don't understand is how that is a solution? Maybe I am simply not seeing it. I am new to recursion and programming in general. I believe I have my code working towards the base case of 0 do I not?

Comment: @JakeChavis Instead of starting drawing when it is really small, you need to stop drawing when it is really small. Invert the condition.

Comment: @JakeChavis if (level > 0)

Comment: @RobinGreen I put that in my program and it did the same thing as it was doing before.

Comment: I've been warned to avoid extended discussion in comments by the site. Please raise a new question, and let's close this one.

Comment: @RobinGreen correct that, it actually only draws a straight line.

Comment: @RobinGreen I was told to delete the post. Just leave an answer so it doesn't fill the comments

Comment: Sorry, I realised that my idea of inverting the condition is probably wrong. Maybe you just need to increase your length parameter to make it longer?

Comment: @RobinGreen nothing seems to be working. I will ask my teacher about it tomorrow. Thanks for helping !

Comment: Your code seems to work with `level` = 2 or 3. I get some weird output with level=5, but that's probably the drawing framework I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

if you hand iterate your loop a few times perhaps what is happening will become clear; or put printfs() in all paths and printout level and length next and next function to be called.

```
initial conditions:  level = 2, length = 9
stack  enter       level     length     action
0      draw        2         9          call draw(1, 3)
1      draw        1         3          call draw(0, 1)
2      draw        0         1          myPencil.forward(1); return;
1                  1         3          myPencil.turnLeft(60); call draw(0, 1)
2      draw        0         1          myPencil.forward(1); return;
1                  1         3          myPencil.turnRight(120); call draw(0, 1)
2      draw        0         1          myPencil.forward(1); return;
1                  1         3          myPencil.turnLeft(60); call draw(0, 1)
2      draw        0         1          myPencil.forward(1); return;
1                  1         3          return;
0                  2         9          myPencil.turnLeft(60); call draw(1, 3)
     repeat steps above starting at line 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to `myLength`, which is presumably staying constant, instead of the actual method argument, `length`. That's what's decreasing, so you should use that.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed that but even when I do this only a dot appears on the screen. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: you haven't provided enough code to determine what's wrong, although I suspect you are somehow passing 0 as a length argument.

Comment: @RobinGreen At a glance, my guess is a integer division issue.

Comment: @brimborium The code in the question was changed about 20 minutes ago; it was `int`s when I posted the comment.

Comment: @DennisMeng Oh, I see. That's not ideal... ;)